# Is there a ready made identity provider in azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

Just trying to understand the concept of Azure AD. 
I understand that it has all federated identity concepts to log in a user based on some third part provider like Facebook and Google.

But what if a user want to register to your app instead. Cant i use azure to simply pass my email and password and a user is created. and i get change password and forgot password like basic service out of the box instead of me creating an asp.net identity based web apis and maintain identity database in 
 SQL and expose this system to my clients.

let me know if i am thinking in wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

Have a look at [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/)

**Edit:**

> Azure AD B2C is a cloud identity management solution for your web and mobile applications. It is a highly available global service that scales to hundreds of millions of identities. Built on an enterprise-grade secure platform, Azure AD B2C keeps your applications, your business, and your customers protected.
>
> With minimal configuration, Azure AD B2C enables your application to authenticate:
>
> - Social Accounts (such as Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, and more)
> - Enterprise Accounts (using open standard protocols, OpenID Connect or
>     SAML)
> - Local Accounts (email address and password, or username and
>     password)

With AAD B2C it's super simple to get up & running. But you're also able to customize it exactly the way you want it. Think about Sign-in & sign-up policies, branded login pages, password reset and even optional Multifactor Authentication.

For more information and examples in multiple languages: [Azure AD B2C: Focus on your app, let us worry about sign-up and sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview)

Comment: Azure AD B2C is a good choice for this. It would be good if you could write in a bit more detail how B2C allows doing all those things.

Comment: so i see that b2c takes me to a web page and we log in there. we can also customize the page. 

but what if we want to click a login button on a mobile app and make a call to azure b2c like we do in REST. it checks if user exists it returns token . if does not it gives an error and we navigate to Register page (in our mobile app) and register button calls Azure ad b2c and creates new user??

Comment: @RaasMasood Did you have a look at the examples? There are iOS, Android, Xamarin and .NET examples for mobile apps. BTW it's not cool to remove the answer checkmark just because you have follow-up questions, especially when your initial question was answered. Please open a new question if you have any _programming_ questions. And don't forget to mention what you tried yourself and what doesn't work for you.

Comment: If you use Azure AD B2C, you are federating the authentication to them. It means you will not use your app's views to register/login.

Comment: Is there anything like that out there?